# Adding a delay in AngularJS forEach

Tags: angularjs, foreach, timeout, intervals

I'm trying to put a delay in a forEach loop in AngularJS. With $timeout, they're firing once at the same time. With $interval, they're caught in an infinite loop, again at the same time.

I need the function delay between iterations of the forEach loop to fire the animations in delayed succession rather than at the same time.

```
...
vm.questions = [
    {correct:false,animateDemo:false},
    {correct:true,animateDemo:false}, 
    {correct:true,animateDemo:false}
];

vm.questions.forEach(function(question, idx) {
    // need a delay between animationDemo assignments
    $timeout(function(){
      if (question.correct) {
        question.animateDemo = true;
      }
    },1000);
  });
```

I tried interval too, but that causes an infinite loop.

```
vm.questions = [{correct:false}. {correct:true}, {correct:true}];


vm.questions.forEach(function(question, idx) {
    // causes infinite loop
    $interval(function(){
      if (question.correct) {
        question.animateDemo = true;
      }
    },1000);
  });
```

I'm sure the solution is probably something simple, but getting it in this syntax is a bit confusing to me personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is have a dynamic timeout for each question animation.

Something like this:

```
var timeoutTimer = 1000;
vm.questions.forEach(function(question, idx) {
    $timeout(function(){
      if (question.correct) {
        question.animateDemo = true;
      }
    }, timeoutTimer);
    timeoutTimer += 1000;
  });
```

You want to use `$timeout` and not `$interval` since you only want each animation to trigger once.  `$interval` will execute every x seconds until you cancel it.

`$timeout` is a promise so code will continue to execute while it waits for the delay.  This is why it appears they are all firing at the same time.  They actually are probably a few nanoseconds apart from each other.